# Querying for all fields in a document

Tags: ravendb

I want use gather all data within a database in RavenDB. Similar to SELECT * in SQL.

```
from @all_docs 
select {
    Name: Value
}
```

Instead of typing in all possible names and their corresponding values, I am wondering if there is an "all" character.

Answer (score 1):

```
from @all_docs
```

should return all the documents